# Как загрузить JSON и отрисовать список с данными в List?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

Всем привет, я только начал изучать SWIFT. Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу сделать запрос и обработав список отобразить его в View(На примере параметра "name" в JSON).
Вот моя структура:

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    var groups: [Group] = []
    var goods: [Good] = []
}

struct Good: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let name, text: String?
    let price: Int?
    let unit: String?
    let index, img: String?
    let groups: [String]?
}

struct Group: Codable {
    let id, name, img: String?
}
```

Вот пример JSON:

```
 {
"groups": [

{
"id": "123",
"name": "test",
"img": "123"
}
],
"goods": [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "123",
"text": "123",
"price": 75,
"unit": "123",
"index": "123",
"img": "123",
"groups": [
"123"
]
}
}
```

Я использую SWIFTUI 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Гуглим `swiftui fetch json`
2. [Открываем](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/swiftui-json-list-tutorial) первую же ссылку с примером
3. Загоняем ваши данные в [Mocky](https://designer.mocky.io/), параллельно исправив скобки и отформатировав

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "test",
      "img": "123"
    }
  ],
  "goods": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "123",
      "text": "123",
      "price": 75,
      "unit": "123",
      "index": "123",
      "img": "123",
      "groups": [
        "123"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

4. Копипастим код и подгоняем под наши нужды

```
// ...
struct Good: Codable, Identifiable { // -- added Identifiable for List
    let id: Int?
    let name, text: String?
    let price: Int?
    let unit: String?
    let index, img: String?
    let groups: [String]?
}
// ...
```

Используется связка observable / obverved для уведомления о получении данных

```
class MyJsonData : ObservableObject {
    
    // 1.
    @Published var welcome = Welcome()
    
    init() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/fd0b7535-2718-4f44-acd2-0e4c86af69bd")!
        // 2.
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let todoData = data {
                    // 3.
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: todoData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.welcome = decodedData
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // 1.
    @ObservedObject var myJsonData = MyJsonData()
    
    let data = [""]
    
    var body: some View {
        // 2.
        List(myJsonData.welcome.goods) { good in
            // 3.
            Text(good.name ?? "Unknown good")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно разбить задачу на подзадачу.

- Получить данные (локально / веб-запрос)
- Спарить данные
- Обернуть в модели
- Сконфигурировать UI

Каждая из задач отдельный вопрос. Кода слишком много. Начните с первого пункта - в вебе есть информация.

Comment: в данном случае мне надо понять как обработать запрос и достать из него данные. Я знаю, что реализация должна быть с использованием URLSession.shared.dataTask и JSONDecoder().decode, но вот как это объединить и разбить данные в структуру не знаю.